# Does changing the configuration Kill the App and Restart it?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate

I was reading [This Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html) section 6.1. And it says that, changing the configuration of an App causes the App to Restart?

My question is, in what sense the App would Restart? does it mean that when the configuration changes, `onStop()` then `onCreate()` will be called? But this only happens when another App with higher priority needs memory!

OR

In the sense that, the `onStop()` then `onRestart()` then `onStart()` will be called?

I created a sample App, with only `onCreate()` callback and with a `Log` statement, and every time I re-orient the device, the `Log` statement displays `@onCreate()` does it mean that changing the configuration of the App. causes it to be killed and restarted over and calls `onCreate()` again?

kindly please clarify it if possible

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is not killed an restarted.

Your Activity will, however, be *recreated.*

If you think about how an Activity's layout can be changed when the device is rotated, this makes sense. If you have a portrait layout in your `layout/` folder and and landscape layout in your `layout-land/` folder, then Android will need to destroy the Activity and recreate it with the new layout.