# Android: LeakCanary for fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I have an app with one activity and 4 fragments.

I want to make sure that LeakCanary is installed correctly so I can check a suspicious memory leak in my app. I don't get anything for it so I wanted to simulate one but failed. I read on how to leak an activity but I have only one.

In MainActivity, I did the following:

```
private static RefWatcher refWatcher;
public static RefWatcher getRefWatcher() {
    return MainActivity.refWatcher;
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
            // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
            // You should not init your app in this process.
            return;
        }
        refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(getApplication());
...
}
```

In fragment X, I did the following:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    RefWatcher refWatcher = MainActivity.getRefWatcher();
    refWatcher.watch(this);
}

void registerListener() {
    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
    sensorManager.registerListener(new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    }, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

In onCreate of the fragment, I did this

```
final ImageView ivSort = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivSort);
ivSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   registerListener();
   Utils.selectMenuItem(((MainActivity) getActivity()).navigation.getMenu().getItem(0),(MainActivity) getActivity(),-1);
}
```

When my app starts, it will open fragment X. When clicking ivSort, it will register a listener and immediately move to fragment Y, assuming the lack of unregistering the listener, will cause a leak but nothing happens.

Please advice, I'm lost
Thanks

**Edited, went on a different approach:**

MainActivity's onCreate:

```
if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
    // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
    // You should not init your app in this process.
    return;
}
LeakCanary.install(getApplication());
Utils.leak = this;
```

add a class Utils.java

```
public static Activity leak;
```

And I changed from portrait to landscape and back. LeakCanary is sleeping.
What am I missing?

Comment: I guess the Listener does not hold on to anything related to the Activity/ the Fragment, at most to the Application Context (which would not be destroyed because of an orientation change, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26385097/5015207)). But you could change that - let it have a member variable of type Activity and assign your Activity instance to it. Does the LeakCanary react to this?

Comment: "let it have a member variable of type Activity" -> what is it? Also, the activity won't be destroyed because it's the same activity only different fragment. This is why I tried the registerListener (without unregistering|) instead of the activity reference (from the list of possible leaks)

Comment: I'm going to post an answer to clarífy - not because I'm sure it will work but because a comment does not offer enough space :)

Comment: Really sorry I can't help you. Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153410/cant-find-the-leak-on-my-fragment-android-code) will be helpful - good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I followed all docs but nothing. I created an application class, moved everything there, leaked my mainactivity and changed configuration to trigger activity destroy but nothing from leakcanary